# Unable to import gpiozero

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpiozero

I just installed the full & latest (November 2017) raspbian to try out gpiozero. My simple python3 script that I try to run is this:

python3 test.py

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

led = LED(17)
button = Button(3)

button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_released = led.off

pause()
```

but it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gpiozero import LED, Button
  File "/home/pi/gpiozero.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gpiozero import LED
ImportError: cannot import name 'LED'
```

So it is just not able to see the lib. By now I've checked apt-get and also tried pip for 2.7 and pip3 for python 3 but it's just not found? Must be super simple...

Answer (score 1):

I know it is almost a year old question, but I found the answer.
Uninstall the pip and pip3 libraries

```
sudo pip uninstall gpiozero
sudo pip3 uninstall gpiozero
```

and install the library through apt

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-gpiozero python-gpiozero
```

that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You have another file called `gpiozero.py`, and so your `from gpiozero import LED` tries to import it from that file, not from the libraries path.

You can tell because in your traceback it says `/home/pi/gpiozero.py`:

```
File "/home/pi/gpiozero.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gpiozero import LED
ImportError: cannot import name 'LED'
```

Rename your file to something else, and it will work.